# meteor mogodb upsert a nested array of object with _id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor, upsert

mongo version: `4.4.4`

In my meteorJs application, I have a collection called `packages` and I want to "upsert" the `services` array of objects based on its `_id`. upon researching i found out that one way to do that is to pull the object from the array and then push the object to the array

here is how i am doing it now

```
function updatePackage(pkgId = 'cKB6gkvP76HYiDs7W', serviceId = "e8RfhPdAh2rpsJPFb"){
    const service = ServicesCollection.findOne({
      _id: serviceId,
    });

    PkgsCollection.update(
      { _id: pkgId },
      {
        $pull: {
          services: {
            _id: serviceId,
          },
        },
      },
      { multi: true }
    );
    PkgsCollection.update(
      { _id: pkgId },
      {
        $push: {
          services: service,
        },
      }
    );
}
```

this is not working currently and my packages collection ends up below:

```
{
        "_id" : "cKB6gkvP76HYiDs7W",
        "pkgName" : "pkg1",
        "owner" : "own1",
        "services" : [
                {
                        "_id" : "e8RfhPdAh2rpsJPFb",
                        "serviceName" : "serv1",
                },
                {
                        "_id" : "e8RfhPdAh2rpsJPFb",
                        "serviceName" : "serv1",
                }
        ],
}
```

but in mongo shell this following commands works perfectly fine

```
db.pkgs.update(
  {_id:"cKB6gkvP76HYiDs7W"},
  {
    $pull:{
      services:{
        _id:"e8RfhPdAh2rpsJPFb"
      }
    }
  });
```

Why is this not working and is there a better way to upsert object in an array without the two push and pull operations?

edit: updated the typo `PkgsCollection.find` to `PkgsCollection.update` and added more code for context

Comment: try to use async/await, put await before `await PkgsCollection.update(`

Comment: Can you please show your entire code around this? Your first statement is a `find`, which of course doesn't pull anything, and in your second statement you use a variable `service` as if we are meant to understand what that is.

Comment: @ChristianFritz i updated the code and fixed the typo `find`. Please let me know your suggestions

Comment: silly question: why is your default serviceId value the same as the pkgId?

Comment: sorry, i cant seem to make enough typos. fixed it again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and errors, i found out in meteor documentation (https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-rawCollection) that the `collection.rawcollection()` gives the actual collection object from the meteor wrapper. So changing the pull object from array code to the following worked for me

```
 PkgsCollection.rawCollection().update(
      { _id: pkgId },
      {
        $pull: {
          services: {
            _id: serviceId,
          },
        },
      }
    );
```